# Node.js sort mongodb-results when searchvalue is an array

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I had to change the schema from "name"(string) to "name"(object) {DE:"", EN:"").

Now im having troubles to sort the complete results by the german/english name. Can someone give me a hint how to access that?

The mongodb-Example is looking like:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: { DE: 'Beispiel 2', EN: 'Example 2' },
  type: 'Audio',
  ...
},
{ 
  _id: 2,
  name: { DE: 'Beispiel 3', EN: 'Example 3' },
  type: 'Audio',
},
{ 
  _id: 3,
  name: { DE: 'Beispiel 1', EN: 'Example 1' },
  type: 'Audio',
},
...
```

this is how i sorted the results before (name was a simple string).

```
getFiles: function (callback) {

    media.find({type: 'Audio'}).sort('name').exec(function (err, media){
        if (!err) {
            callback(media);
        }
        else callback(null);
    });
}
```

**Udpate:**
The result should be sorted by english or german name:

```
id 3 (Example 1)
id 1 (Example 2)
id 2 (Example 3)
```

**Update 2**
Before the changes, the name was a simple string:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'Example 2',
  type: 'Audio',
  ...
},
```

what is the best way to sort the results using the english or german name?

Thx 4 help :)

Comment: What you seem to be wanting to do is sort within the document that is returned by your search. 
Your current sort will sort all the results but not within the documents that are returned.
You should probably sort after the result has been returned.
I suspect that your question was down-voted because of your mis-understanding of what you are actually doing.

Comment: I still want to sort all the results, not just the single documents. Sorry, my english is not very good ;)

Comment: Do you want to search based on the English or the German name? 
The problem is that you now have an array in the name rather than a string. 
To sort by english name you may be able to use .sort('name.EN') - Not tested.
However, it may be better to look at your document structure.

Comment: thats exactly my problem ;) i was sorting the results by name(string), now they decided to make that an array. and 'name.EN' doen't seem to work

Comment: Do you want to sort by English name, German name, or both? Can you post a sample name before the change? Did it already support both languages?

Comment: right now it doesn't matter if it's EN or DE.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would need to sort by the relevant language in the function.
I also think there is an error in your code around the sorting. Try the below to sort by EN.

```
getFiles: function (callback) {
 media.find({type: 'Audio'}, {sort: {'name.EN': 1}}).exec(function (err, media){
    if (!err) {
        callback(media);
    }
    else callback(null);
 });
}
```

Comment: looks like 'name.EN' doen't work. i get the same result if i use 'name' or 'name.EN'. And its not alphabetically sorted.

Comment: Have you used the updated code where the sort is within the find()?: media.find({type: 'Audio'}, {sort: {'name.EN': 1}}).exec(function (err, media)